# How to use stopPropagation() with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am trying to use stopPropagation so my dropdown menu will close after I click on any other elements.

When I try to use stopPropagation & updating a boolean state the button re-render the page (which reset the state back to 'false') than updating the state to true and it stuck on "true" no matter what.

I wrote a code for an example:

```html
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function IndexPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", () => {
      setState(false);
    });
  });

  const onButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setState(!state);
  };

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Click</button>

      <h1>{state ? "true" : "false"}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This problem seems to appear **only** with Next.js

I wrote the same code with React app and there is no problem.

Next.js codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-nash-u25bk?file=/pages/index.js:0-484)

React codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-dew-d9yuo?file=/src/App.tsx)

Edit:

When you fork the Next.js sandbox project everything is working fine. (and yet it doesn't solve the problem with my original code).

Anyone knows why is it happening?

Comment: It's good practice to clear all event listeners on component unmount. You should call `removeEventListener` in your `useEffect` return statement, to remove the `click` event listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did found a fix for this bug and the first person Who comment me solved this issue.

I add to my code a cleanup for my event listener and it seems to solve the problem.

It seems like cleanup inside useEffect is not just a good practice but a "must".

Because of the cleanup useEffect re-render the page twice and not three times and it prevent it from another render which cause the problem.

Big thanks for anyone tried to help.

The fixed code is:

```html
export default function IndexPage() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("click", () => setState(false)); 

    return () => window.removeEventListener("click", () => setState(false)); 
  });

  const onButtonClick = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    setState(!state);
  };

  console.log(state);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Click</button>

      <h1>{state ? "true" : "false"}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Next.js sandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-nash-u25bk?file=/pages/index.js:596-1089)

Comment: Hey @Uria good that it got solved for you. Yes you should always return a cleanup function in useEffect to remove any listeners. But I think you were not saving your changes after each edit earlier. In React setup it's not necessary to save changes since on each edit you get a re-render. This doesn't seem to be the case with Next.js in codesandbox. When you save in Next Js container only then your new changes reflect and so even if you now remove the cleanup code and save again, you will still see it working.

Comment: It will work because e.stopPropagation will still be in effect and irrespective of how many times an event handler got added to window, your event will not pass through so doesn't matter if previous listener got cleared or not. 
Adding my fork with same code of yours before and it will still work - https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-voice-qr5b1?file=/pages/index.js

Comment: Thank you for the comment and your time,

I do save my project even if I add ";"(after formatting of course) . On my first post I edit and added that when I fork the project the code is working without a problem but yet solving the problem with my code (I wrote just an example, it is not my code and I write my code on VS).

I tried to even promote my project to production to see if it would change anything, but it does not.

So even if I fork my project on Codesandbox it won't solve the problem which occurs in my original code or even at production status.

Answer (score 3):

This is a strange one. In the codesandbox container the state is getting preserved for overtime edits and not causing any re-renders as well so probably your `e.stopPropagation` when added to event handler didn't trigger a re-render and so the old handler for the button is still attached which means that the event listener on the body will keep on triggering as you click the button since our handler never got updated to factor in `e.stopPropagation`.

When I fork your Next.js setup, everything works fine. Because it's not an incremental change now. The container is rebuilt for me and doesn't preserve any past state and so no stale event handlers or anything.

The best way to test the difference between both setup is to see if the console logs any value when you remove the `e.stopPropagation` line from both. You will see that Next.js doesn't but the React one does. That means React's state even though preserved still triggered a render and so on new render the event handler that got created knows that :-

> Hey, I don't have `e.stopPropagation` anymore so my
> event will bubble up

**Update** - It seems that hitting Save after each change is necessary with Next.js container for a re-render. Don't rely on edits alone like in case of React container.

Comment: Thank you,

I tried to remove the e.stopPropagation line, and yet it render as before. it rendering the page three times for each click while in react it rendering it once for each click.

I still couldn't solve the issue when you double click on the button it will change from 'true' to 'false' with next.

Comment: Doing edits in your Next js container isn’t causing a re-render which is the real issue (I think Fast refresh is the culprit). Your event handler is behaving as it was when you first created it probably without e.stopPropgation and even adding / removing the same to it isn’t causing any re-renders so that a new handler can be bound to your button. I am currently not aware of how exactly to fix it in the container url you shared. If you fork your container, you will see things working as it should be.

Comment: Hopefully some body more experienced sees this question and brings in more insights as to root cause and fix.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I found a way, nextjs version 13
The fixed code is:

```
onClick={(event) => { foo(); event.stopPropagation() }}
```